# Razor: use my layout like a normal view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In some specific cases I need to use my layout like a regular view with a model. The problem is that I get error where my RenderSection is defined. Is there any function to tell me if my layout has a child view? Or could RenderSection be a optional definition? Any solution is good. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you might not actually have a section to render in a layout, you can either use IsSectionDefined

```
@if(IsSectionDefined("mySection"){
    @RenderSection("mySection")
    }
```

or just pass in false to the RenderSection call's second, optional argument:

```
@RenderSection("mySection", required: false)
```